# How can I iterate through an <ul> using a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a kind of a help bar on the right side of the screen for a website.

[image: sidebar help]

I have an index highlighted by a class; How can iterate through the  using this "next" button and highlighting each step?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1wvd690h/

HTML:

```
<button id="next-help">Next</button>

<ul id="helpBar-list" class="no-indent">
    <li class="highlight">Click on Online PO's</li>
    <li>Select the 'Total' Folder</li>
    <li>Type the name of th Supplier in the filter box</li>
    <li>Open a PO containing the items you need by clicking on the PO Number</li>
    <li>Review the PO Contents</li>
    <li>If this Purchase Order has the items you need, click on the 'Copy' icon</li>
    <li>Clicky 'Copy &amp; New' in the prompt</li>
    <li>Change quantities as necessary</li>
    <li>Review, and submit your order when ready</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#next-help").click(function (){
    //should go to next index in <ul>
});

var listItems = $("#helpBar-list li");

listItems.each(function (index)
{
    //this is how i am looping through entire list, but i don't need to do that
    console.log(index + ": " + $(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
$("#next-help").on("click",function (){
  $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight").next().addClass("highlight");
});
```

to loop and save index for storage

```
$(function() {
  var $list = $("#helpBar-list li");   
  $("#next-help").on("click",function (){
    var idx = $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight").next().index();
    if(idx==-1) idx=0; // here you can do what you want with idx
    $list.eq(idx).addClass("highlight");
  });
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/19oepnv8/)

```js
$(function() {
  var $list = $("#helpBar-list li");   
  $("#next-help").on("click",function (){
    var idx = $(".highlight")
      .removeClass("highlight")
      .next()
      .index();
    if(idx==-1) idx=0;
    $list.eq(idx).addClass("highlight");
    console.log(idx);  
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="next-help">Next</button>

<ul id="helpBar-list" class="no-indent">
    <li class="highlight">Click on Online PO's</li>
    <li>Select the 'Total' Folder</li>
    <li>Type the name of th Supplier in the filter box</li>
    <li>Open a PO containing the items you need by clicking on the PO Number</li>
    <li>Review the PO Contents</li>
    <li>If this Purchase Order has the items you need, click on the 'Copy' icon</li>
    <li>Clicky 'Copy &amp; New' in the prompt</li>
    <li>Change quantities as necessary</li>
    <li>Review, and submit your order when ready</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: nice I didnt know 'next' existed! You'll have to manage going from last to first if im not mistaken though

Answer (score 2):

One more solution:

```js
var listItems = $("#helpBar-list li");
var i = listItems.filter('.highlight').index();

$("#next-help").click(function () {
    listItems.removeClass('highlight').eq(++i % listItems.length).addClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
.highlight {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="next-help">Next</button>
<ul id="helpBar-list" class="no-indent">
    <li class="highlight">Click on Online PO's</li>
    <li>Select the 'Total' Folder</li>
    <li>Type the name of th Supplier in the filter box</li>
    <li>Open a PO containing the items you need by clicking on the PO Number</li>
    <li>Review the PO Contents</li>
    <li>If this Purchase Order has the items you need, click on the 'Copy' icon</li>
    <li>Clicky 'Copy &amp; New' in the prompt</li>
    <li>Change quantities as necessary</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hm, what exactly is overkill, simpler and more effective code?

Comment: 1) using filter 2) using remainder - I think my if is easier to grasp for any level of coder. I see you save a line but still. It can be considered more elegant but much harder to read

Comment: However I don't know which has better performance `next` or `eq`. Need to run perfs, maybe you are right. Filter is not an issue, it's executed only once to get the selected index.

Comment: @mplungjan And I would say that your version has the performance issue as it might be good idea to cache selector.

Comment: I think in this particular case it does not matter. You mean `var $hl = $(".highlight")` ? - that cannot be cached - it will force user to click twice at the end. Good night

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, as simple as this. It also loops back to the beginning when it reaches the end:

```
var listItemCount = $('#helpBar-list li').length; // counts # of <li>
var current = 0; // current <li> index you are on

$('#next-help').on('click', function() {
    // Remove the highlight on the <li> and place it on the next one
    $('#helpBar-list li.highlight').removeClass('highlight').next().addClass('highlight');
    current++;

    // Once it reaches the end, loop back
    if(current == listItemCount) {
        $('#helpBar-list li:first-child').addClass('highlight');
        current = 0;        
    }
});
```

Here's the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1wvd690h/1/

Comment: Thank you.. I used this answer because I also needed to use the "current" index that you specified so that the option would persist (through localstorage) across different pages

Answer (score 1):

use addClass, removeClass and next()

```js
$("#next-help").click(function() {
  $("#helpBar-list")
    .find(".highlight").removeClass("highlight")
    .next("li").addClass("highlight");
});
```

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="next-help">Next</button>

<ul id="helpBar-list" class="no-indent">
  <li class="highlight">Click on Online PO's</li>
  <li>Select the 'Total' Folder</li>
  <li>Type the name of th Supplier in the filter box</li>
  <li>Open a PO containing the items you need by clicking on the PO Number</li>
  <li>Review the PO Contents</li>
  <li>If this Purchase Order has the items you need, click on the 'Copy' icon</li>
  <li>Clicky 'Copy &amp; New' in the prompt</li>
  <li>Change quantities as necessary</li>
  <li>Review, and submit your order when ready</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to create the `<li>` with an id so you can iterate through them otherwise your javascript will always return either all the li, or the very first (or you could also get the very first that DOESNT have the highlighted class but this will still not do what you want)

If you give them ids, you find your element that is highlighted with its class, and read its id, then remove the highlight class. do +1 to its id (find the relevant element) and set the highlight class to that element.